# Mongoose: multi: true for a projection update doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Having a document with the following structure:

```
{
   _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' },
   notifications: [{
      story: {
         _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' },
         video_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' }
      },
      video: {
         _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' },
         video_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' }
      },
      type: { type: String },
      read: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // 0 - Unread, 1 - read
      ts: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to mark as read all notifications which `read` element equals to 0, but for any reason, my code only modifies the first notification:

```
mongoose.model('User').update({ _id: user_id, 'notifications.read': 0 }, { $set: { 'notifications.$.read': 1 }}, { multi: true });
```

Am I using correctly the `multi: true`?

**UPDATE**

I'd say what I'm trying to do, doesn't have any sense by using the [placeholder](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) since as the doc says:

> $. Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the query condition in an update.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{ _id: user_id, 'notifications.read': 0 }` this to update the document, it will only find one document, because you are querying by the `_id`.

You should use `{'notifications.read': 0 }` instead.

Comment: testing your answer, even if I remove the `_id: user_id`, It keeps updating me the first notification

Comment: Are you using `multi:true` to update the `notifications` sub-document or the main documents?

Comment: as I've specified in the description, I'm trying to update all subdocuments which `read` attribute equals 0

Comment: `multi:true` cannot update the sub documents. It updates all the main documents matching the criteria. In your case I thought notifications was the main document. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `$` placeholder, but to modify multiple embedded documents in one query it's necessary to use the `arrayFilters` as well, as specified [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#examples). Also, you don't have to use `multi: true`.

In your case it would look like this:

```js
mongoose.model('User').updateOne(
    { _id: user_id },
    { $set: { 'notifications.$[element].read': 1 } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'element.read': 0 }] }
)
```